# Cookies from localhost not setting in browser

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, cookies

I am sending cookies using Express and when I query to the correct api endpoint from Postman I can see the cookie I am setting. I am not specifying the domain which I have read is the correct thing to do, so my IP address is listed as the domain and this includes 3 '.'s which I have also read is a requirement for browsers to save a cookie from localhost.

However, when I go to the correct page in my web app on localhost, I can tell it is querying the correct API endpoint, yet no cookies are shown in the chrome developer console, nor are they shown in firefox. I am new to cookies and sessions and I would like to get an understanding of cookies before I try a session, but I have been struggling for hours to make Chrome set a cookie and it won't work.

I am running Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) of Chrome.

Here is my code from my API where I am setting the cookie:

```
var express   = require('express');
var router    = express.Router();

router.get('/SalesReps',(req,res,next) => {
  {
    res.cookie('cookie','value',{maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365});
    res.end();
  }
});
```

I have tried several maxAge's so I am pretty confident that this is not the issue.

Can anyone explain how I can make Chrome save the cookie I am sending it?

Comment: Have you tried window.document.cookie in the JS console ?

Comment: @jmugz3 I'm not really sure what you mean by that

Comment: You can view your cookies in the Javascript console of your developer tools in your browser. I am not 100% sure, but I believe Chrome ignores cookies coming from localhost

Comment: @jmugz3 ah ok I see what you mean now, but it just returns "" rather than a cookie. I knew that Chrome ignores cookies from localhost, though. I am asking about a way to make it not ignore them